# Searching a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, list

So I want to use one of these LINQ functions with this `List<string>` I have.

Here's the setup:

```
List<string> all = FillList();
string temp = "something";
string found;
int index;
```

I want to find the `string` in `all` that matches `temp` when both are lower cased with `ToLower()`. Then I'll use the found string to find it's index and remove it from the list.

How can I do this with LINQ?

Comment: Well I wasn't sure if I should use `Where` or `Find` or something else.

Comment: Do you want to compare the lower-cased versions, or do you want to compare *and ignore the case*? Don't use lower/uppercase comparisons just to achieve a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: What if there are duplicates? What index you want to return? First? Last? Also check 101 Linq samples on msdn.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I want to ignore case.

Comment: @TomasVoracek if there are dupes I want the first, but honestly it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Why do you want to use Linq for that? Is it a need or just to know how to do in Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the feeling that you don't care so much about comparing the lowercase versions as you do about just performing a case-insensitive match. If so:

```
var listEntry = all.Where(entry => 
          string.Equals(entry, temp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
         .FirstOrDefault();

if (listEntry != null) all.Remove(listEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see [my imperative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787880/533120) is not getting any love, so here is a LINQ solution that is probably less efficient, but still avoids searching through the list two times (which is a problem in the accepted answer):

```
var all = new List<string>(new [] { "aaa", "BBB", "Something", "ccc" });
const string temp = "something";

var found = all
    .Select((element, index) => new {element, index})
    .FirstOrDefault(pair => StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(temp, pair.element));

if (found != null)
    all.RemoveAt(found.index);
```

---

You could also do this (which is probably more performant than the above, since it does not create new object for each element):

```
var index = all
    .TakeWhile(element => !StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(temp, element))
    .Count();

if (index < all.Count)
    all.RemoveAt(index);
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to previous answers... why don't you just do it like this :

```
string temp = "something";
List<string> all = FillList().Where(x => x.ToLower() != temp.ToLower());
```

Then you have the list without those items in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
all.Remove(all.FirstOrDefault(
            s => s.Equals(temp,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: -1 This will throw an exception on duplicates. And that method of removing an element by index boggles the mind.

Comment: Yeah, right, I edited with firstOrDefault. There are many ways to do this

Comment: Actually, I would never think of Linq to do this, I would just call the remove method of the List

Comment: `List.Remove()` does not allow for custom comparisons, such as doing so in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: This should work: all = all.Select(str => str.ToLower()).ToList();           all.Remove(temp.ToLower());

Comment: That creates a new list consisting entirely of the lowercase representation of the former list, then removes the element from that. Not only does this do nothing to the original list (which may be referenced elsewhere), it also changes the content of EVERY element, rather than just removing the element in question. And, incidentally, that uses LINQ, which you said you were opposed to.

Comment: Awww, sometimes I code without thinking!! ^^ I must admit that Linq is the fastest way to do this, or it would require a for and a use of the removeAt function.

Answer (score -3):

Use the tool best suited for the job. In this case a simple piece of procedural code seems more appropriate than LINQ:

```
var all = new List<string>(new [] { "aaa", "BBB", "Something", "ccc" });
const string temp = "something";
var cmp = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase; // Or another comparer of you choosing.

for (int index = 0; index < all.Count; ++index) {
    string found = all[index];
    if (cmp.Equals(temp, found)) { 
        all.RemoveAt(index);
        // Do whatever is it you want to do with 'found'.
        break;
    }
}
```

This is probably as fast as you can get, because:

- Comparison it done in place - there is no creation of temporary uppercase (or lowercase) strings just for comparison purposes.
- Element is searched only once (O(index)).
- Element is removed in place without constructing a new list (O(all.Count-index)).
- No delegates are used.
- Straight `for` tends to be faster than `foreach`.

It can also be adapted fairly easily should you want to handle duplicates.

Comment: LINQ is intended to create clarity and brevity, not performance. This solution is much longer and more difficult to determine what is going on. If raw performance is your goal, then LINQ is *rarely* the right tool for the job. But raw performance is also rarely the chief goal.

Comment: You can't change a collection while looping thru it.

Comment: @Fischermaen Sure I can - if I'm using index and not enumerator.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Searching through the container more times than absolutely necessary (as in your answer) can bite you fairly easily once you have finished debugging and actually try to run your program on realistic amounts of data (or worse yet, customer runs it). This is especially true if you are doing it systematically throughout your program. A lot of sluggishness we see in "enterprise" software is a direct consequence of this kind of thinking. Also, this piece of code can be easily wrapped in an extension method and properly documented, making the call-site super clear.

Comment: I will agree that different circumstances call for different approaches. What I won't agree to is that "realistic amounts of data" necessarily means that a bit of code that sacrifices performance for readability will perform unacceptably. Are there such situations? Sure. Is the OP in such a situation? I don't know, and neither do you. The question was about using LINQ, and there's no immediately obvious reason to believe that this is a *bad idea*. See @gwiazdorrr's answer for a readable approach that still only searches the collection once.

Comment: Also, just for the sake of clarification, your rate-of-growth measurements are all O(N). There is no distinction between figures like "O(index)" and "O(all.Count-index)".

Comment: @AdamRobinson I mostly agree on your philosophical points, but don't fully agree where the balance should be by default - in my opinion, unless there is a significant increase in code complexity (which here, there isn't) default to performance. In other words, unless you know, assume your list is huge, not the other way around. BTW, gwiazdorrr's answer is about as long as mine (I actually counted the characters, being fully aware that indentations and identifiers could be made different), and I would argue is not more readable either, but I suppose this can be a matter of taste.

Comment: @AdamRobinson And just to clarify: I'm aware that O(x) is the same thing as O(y) where x != y (and both are constant). I used it more as a notational shorthand to clarify that the number of operations (whether string comparisons or string reference copies) is proportional to the number of elements (i.e. index + all.Count - index = all.Count).

Comment: @AdamRobinson BTW, @gwiazdorrr's answer gives incorrect result - the `Where` is called too early.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Indeed, as the index should be captured before filtering, but wouldn't this be better suited to a comment on his answer?

Comment: @AdamRobinson Indeed. I just though to mention it here too, since you brought it up as a "solution". And then, of course, I forgot to also comment on the relevant answer ;) What baffles me is that I'm still receiving negative votes on this, even though it's the only solution that is correct **and** performant.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: StackOverflow periodically recycles old posts to the top. I notice that I frequently end up getting upvotes for (very, very) old answers I've posted. We can agree to disagree on whether other solutions are "performant", but your answer is not "correct" because it doesn't answer the question. It achieves the same end result, but the OP asked how to accomplish the goal with LINQ. Giving another solution is perfectly fine, but it's customary to answer the question in the manner requested unless it's just a horrendously bad idea (or impossible).

Comment: @AdamRobinson That's what I meant by "correct": produces correct result. And answers should be rated on how **helpful** they are, which is different from "correct" as you define it. I had many situations where people asked how to solve a problem using a specific tool, simply because they were unaware that there may be a better tool for the job. In situations like these, deliberately ignoring the tool limitation posited in the question may result in an answer that is ultimately more helpful to the OP. I don't see how my answer qualifies as "unhelpful" in that context.